# Does Bitcoin prefer broadcasting transactions crediting it?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, nodes, coin-age-priority

I'm currently doing some double-spend testing, and it appears that the standard client prefers broadcasting transactions that credit its wallet. That is to say, a client that receives such a transaction broadcasts it more, than it would broadcast other transactions in hopes of getting it into a block sooner. Is this truly the case, or are my observations incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Satoshi client transaction exchange behavior](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Transaction_Exchange), this does not seem to be the case. However, that page isn't written well.  Looking at the [actual source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp), I cannot see any special behavior for transactions to an address in your wallet, but I do see special behavior for transactions from such an address.

Thus, I do not think the behavior you observed is actually valid, and is more likely a pattern you noticed because human beings are too good at noticing patterns for our own good.